Why isn't every loop null-homotopic?
Let's say we have a loop $\gamma$.
Define $H(s,t) = x_0$ if $t\geq s$ and $\gamma(s-t)$ when $t\leq s$.
$H(s,t)$ is continuous since $\{t\geq s\}$ and $\{ t\leq s\}$ are closed subset of $I\times I$ and the pasting lemma (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasting_lemma).
$H(s,t)$ is well-defined on the boundary $\{t=s\}$.
Also, $H(s,0) = x_0$ and $H(s,1)=x_0$.
Clearly every loop shouldn't be null homotopic from what I understand. Where did I do wrong?
Edit: I think I should've said $H(0,t)=H(1,t)=x_0$.

Your homotopy does not keep the endpoints fixed.

I think I should've said $H(0,t)=H(1,t)=x_0$, which I think is true.

Always check your ideas with simple examples.
Work in the punctured plane $\mathbb{R}^2-\{(0,0)\}$. Let $\gamma(t) = (\cos(2\pi t), \sin(2\pi t))$ be the unit circle. Let $x_0 = (1,0)$.
Where does your argument break down?

 Hint: Is your function $H$ actually a homotopy of loops?


Ahh, thank you :)
